# Copying excel rows into specific word text boxes using script

Tags: excel, ms-word

i need to make over 500 graduation certificates for some courses and i wanted to ask if there is a way to copy rows with two columns of Name and Course Name from excel sheet into a pre edited word document with two coresponding text boxes without doing it manualy ?

Comment: Definitely there are ways and you can write script that may do your job.

Comment: You can do it with a script, but it sounds like you probably want to use mail merge instead. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-mail-merge-for-bulk-email-letters-labels-and-envelopes-f488ed5b-b849-4c11-9cff-932c49474705